# flex box css nav bar need the text to be centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

Just a quick question for CSS tailwind
I want the letters in the boxes to be centered within the box, can someone show me what to change to make this ?

At the moment the text in the box are left aligned but the problem is that

```
className={` md:px-[30px]  ease-in duration-100 bg-gray-900 transition-colors ${
    fixed
      ? "fixed w-full h-20 shadow-md z-[100]  bg-gray-900 shadow-gray-900  border-b-2 border-[black]"
      : "  w-full h-20 z-[100] "
  } `}
>
  <div className="flex text-white justify-between items-center w-full h-full pl-[10px] px-2 2xl:px-16 ">
    <div className="relative w-[65px] h-[65px] ">
      <Image
        fill
        src="/projects/logo.jpeg"
        className="absolute object-fill rounded-full  "
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul
        className={` ${
          fixed ? "hidden md:flex text-white" : " hidden md:flex"
        } md:hidden lg:flex`}
      >
        <Link href="/#intro" prefetch={false}>
          <li className="ml-10 text-small uppercase hover-border-b">
            Home
          </li>
        </Link>
```

If possible can you also tell me how to unhide the box layout (the lines that form the box) please

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.  The first example you can use `text-align: center` and `padding-top` properties.  If you calc() 1/2 the height of your element minus 1em, that will center the text top and bottom.

```
text-align: center;
padding-top: calc(50px - 1em);
```

However, this will not ensure the text is centered vertically if the size of your element changes in the future.  A simpler and more robust method is to set your element to `display: flex` with `justify-content` and `align-items` set to center.

```css
#yourDiv {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

```html
<div id="yourDiv">Your text</div>
```

As for the rounded border, that appears to be a CSS class - you may want to search through your code for any `border` properties that are set on the element or pseudo-elements.

Comment: in which div should i put this ?

Comment: In either case, you will want to apply these properties to the div that contains your text.